# Django: Session equivalent of @user_passes_test

Tags: python, django, django-views

I'm familiar with the `@user_passes_test` auth decorator, I'm wondering if there is an equivalent for sessions? Basically I have an account settings page, before heading to the page the user confirms their password, if they succeed then a time stamp is added as a key to their session. I would like to wrap all the other "profile settings" views in a "session passes test" style decorator, which confirms that both the time stamp exists and is less than a certain amount of time old. Is there an easy way to do this? I have several views that need the same logic. So repeating a large chunk of code in each is somewhat obnoxious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

perhaps you want to just write your own decorator to encapsulate all the session logic you want, and apply it to all the "profile settings" views

e.g.  [How to make a chain of function decorators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/739654/understanding-python-decorators)  (they're basically a function which returns a function etc. etc.)